# face recognition using dlib JNI

Tags: face-recognition, dlib

i'm trying to use dlib librery in android.

I have already compiled and added the cpp (.so) file in android and now im stuck in JNI part where i need to get the 128D vector from cpp file to JNI and from JNI to android. Now the problem is i know a way to do this i.e by converting the following c++,

" std::vector < matrix < float,0,1 > > face descriptors = newt(faces)   "

result to JSON in JNI.

Does anyone know how to do it in JNI?

all other approches are appreciated... just need that 128D in android application.

Answer (score 0):

You cant directly use vector what you can do is convert into float[][] as done here
[How to pass a Data from native c binary to android model using JNI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59748010/how-to-pass-a-data-from-native-c-binary-to-android-model-using-jni)